# How to send the items when making a refund of the order?

Tags: magento2, refund

I am creating a module for refunds and I have an error using the method

```
<?php
namespace CrediYa\CrediYa\Controller\CrediYa;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo\CreationArgumentsFactory;

class Refund extends Action
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http */
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Http $request,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\RefundInvoiceInterface $invoiceRefunder,
        CreationArgumentsFactory $creationArguments
  )
  {
        $this->request               = $request;
        $this->invoiceRefunder = $invoiceRefunder;
        $this->creationArguments = $creationArguments;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $items               = [];
        $order_id            = $this->request->getParam('order_id');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order             = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_id);

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) 
        {
            $items[$item->getId()] = array(
                'qty' => $item->getQtyOrdered()
            );

            // $object['order_item_id'] = $item->getId();
            // $object['qty']           = $item->getQtyOrdered();
            
        }

        $invoiceId = null;
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) 
        {
            // this will always point to the latest invoice id
            $invoiceId = $invoice->getId();
        }

        $this->invoiceRefunder->execute(
            $invoiceId, // Invoice ID (NOTE: not increment ID)
            $items,             // Items array (default all)
            false       // false = offline / true = online
        );

    }
}
```

This is the code of my class

In other questions, they said that the $ items argument if it was sent empty, the method would take it as a total return of the order, but when doing this it gives me this error `Exception #0 (Magento\Sales\Exception\DocumentValidationException): Creditmemo Document Validation Error(s): We can't create a credit memo for the invoice.`

On the other hand, if I send something in $ items, this error no longer appears, but it gives another error, which originates from the magento vendor, specifically in this code area.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $data['qtys'][$item->getOrderItemId()] = $item->getQty();
}
```

This is in the file `CredimemoDocumentFactory.php`, What I suppose is that I am sending the articles in the array wrong because it is trying to call a function on each item `getOrderItemId()` and `getQty()`

How should I send the data structure of my $ items array, to solve this error and can magento execute the necessary methods on each element?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, if you want to create a credit memo, then you need to use the below class:

> \Magento\Sales\Api\RefundOrderInterface
> \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface \Magento\Sales\Api\Data
> CreditmemoItemInterfaceFactory

Example:
https://pastebin.com/0tMAAhKX